# how to control masked scrollpane by clicking

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll

I have a bit of a problem. I want to create something like this but vertical instead of horizontal.
I also want to control the slider by clicking on up/down buttons instead of scrolling.

Reference: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/create-a-responsive-xml-image-scroller-in-actionscript-3-0/

Now i have a container mc that holds all my thumbs and a mask that masks that container. I also have my buttons that gonna
trigger this scroll up/scroll down function.

I have sort of no idea at all of how to write the function for that. I have made the container tween up and down but i need a limit
for that so it want tween to far and go out of bounds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, to prevent the mask from moving with the content, make sure it's sitting on the same level as your content.

For example:

```
myContainer ¬
   - contentBox
   - maskShape
```

And `contentBox.mask = maskShape`.

For the scrolling, it's just a matter of increasing or decreasing the position of your contentBox with every click of your navigation buttons.

In the case of the down button, on your event listener you'd do something like...

```
contentBox.y = contentBox.y + 25;
```

Of course we want this to smoothly slide  over, so in the case of [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)...

```
TweenLite.to(contentBox, 0.5, {y:contentBox.y + 25});
```

The "up" button is simply the reverse of this.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like the way to go, and i have got so far now. Now i just don know how to prevent the contentBox to tween to far so it tweens out of sight. Is there a nice way to do a check for that?

Comment: Absolutely.  I'd recommend a ternary operation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).  Assuming your contentBox is 200px, and your maskShape is 100px, and you didn't want to scroll past the bottom, you'd do something like this:  


`contentBox.y = (contentBox.y - 25 <= -100) ? -100 : contentBox.y - 25;`


Basically, we're saying "if the result of moving the box up goes beyond our max location, set it to the max, else use the calculation."  Of course, you could just type this out in an if/else statement, but whatever floats your boat.  ;)